# What happens to an object in an uninstalled OSGi bundle that is being referenced by other threads?

Tags: java, osgi

Let's say I have a Bundle A that has a component B, which is not part of the Export-Package. The component will schedule itself to run periodically once activated. The scheduler is provided by another bundle.

My question is, if I uninstall Bundle A while component B is being run by a thread in the thread pool of the scheduler, what will be the implication? Will the thread continue to run? or will the thread throw exceptions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bundle has a life-cycle. When a bundle is active it will be stopped before it will be uninstalled. If "component B" is a declarative service component it will be stopped as well. If not then at least the stop method in your bundle activator will be triggered.

During stop you (as the provider of component B) are responsible for un-scheduling the component from a schedule so that it will be removed from the thread pool. If the thread is currently running then you should implement a cancelling functionality so that it can be aborted.

If you don't properly cleanup (i.e. un-schedule/cancel the thread) then it may happen that the thread will be executed again. If you access OSGi API from within that thread then you'll get IllegaleStateException (for some API usage because the bundle's BundleContext becomes invalid after being stopped). However, if not then you threads might continue to run forever. Objects and memory won't be released. The classes and the bundle class loader won't be garbage collected. Therefore, it's important that you implement "stop" properly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are binding between modules using proxy references, those proxies can be invalid until you replace the module.

If you have direct bindings, the "uninstalled" module is not really removed until it is not used anywhere.  You can replace it and new uses will use the new library.

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic in OSGi, existing references to objects are maintained and prevent the garbage collector from reaping the corresponding class loader.

Fortunately, DS makes it really easy to do the corresponding cleanup.

Comment: I like this matter-of-fact answer the best. But I think it's important to clarify that the OSGi framework will no longer use that class loader, so new service lookups, etc will not use that loader.